# Get the original value from JFormattedTextField

Tags: java, swing, jformattedtextfield

I'm trying to get original values from MyTextField

```
try {
        MaskFormatter mf1 = new MaskFormatter("##/##/##");
        MyTextField.setFormatterFactory(new DefaultFormatterFactory(mf1));
    }

//input 123456
//System.out.println(MyTextField.getValue());
//display 12/34/56
```

With `MyTextField.getText()` and `MyTextField.getValue()` , I always get `"12/34/56"`. 
Is there any way to get the original value (`123456`) from `MyTextField` ?

Comment: Please show the complete code using `getValue()`.  [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be the best.

Comment: Just remove the formating: `MyTextField.getText().replace("/", "");`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the undesired characters with `MyTextField.getValue().replace("/", "");`

Comment: I cann't use `this` for second parameter, it required a `PropertyChangeListener`

Comment: Just add "implements PropertyChangeListener" in the line where the class is defined and than add the method from @Demogorii

Comment: I figured his IDE would suggest it, that's why I left it out... Thanks :) I edited my answer to mention it.

Comment: I fixed it, it worked but it still returned `/` in value. Did I miss something?

Comment: I updated my answer, just replace the characters, its the simplest solution.